# Adobe Media Encoder rendering issue

Tags: after-effects, adobe-media-encoder, time-lapse, render

I am quite new to the video editing world. I am trying to follow some of tutorial online on how to render a sequence of timelapse photos with Adobe After Effects and export using Media Encoder Queue. Once I add my sequence to the queue and I click on my **.H264** link, I am presented with the following screen:

[image]

Respectively my video is exported with the same content as the one visible on the screenshot.

Weirdly enough, when I export the video using the Render Queue from After Effects, the file looks perfectly fine. After this, I try to re-export the video using again the Media Encoder Queue, and the preview is rendered correctly as well as the final file.

Now when I close, re-open After Effect, make minor change (like aspect ration for example) and attempt to export the video using the Media Encoder Queue. I am given the following screen(where no preview is available):

[image]

A few seconds after I try to export the video, I am getting the following error:

```
------------------------------------------------------------
 - Encoding Time: 00:00:17
05/12/2020 07:52:17 PM : Encoding Failed
------------------------------------------------------------
Export Error
Error compiling movie.

Render Error

Render returned error.

Writing with exporter: H.264
Writing to file: \\?\C:\Users\<user>\Desktop\Timelapse_taranaki\Taranaki_AME\Timelapse_taranaki 2_rendering.mp4
Writing file type: H264
Around timecode: 00:00:00:09
Rendering at offset: 0.000 seconds
Component: H.264 of type Exporter
Selector: 9
Error code: -1609629695
```

When I Purge `All Memory & Disk Cache` and clean the **Common** folder inside **AppData**, I am back to the position of screenshot 1.

I am using **After Effects 2018 Version 15.01(build 73)** and **Media Encoder 2018 Version 12.01(Build 64)** on Windows 10.

```
My configuration is:
Intel(R) i7-4810MQ 2.80GHz
32GB RAM
GPU NVIDIA Quadro K2100M 2GB
```

Anyone has any ideas on what might be the issue here?

Answer (score 1):

I actually was able to find the answer to my question in point **2.** [here](https://helpx.adobe.com/after-effects/kb/after-effects-composition-export-error.html)

Simple add the sequence to the After Effects Render Queue:

[image]

And from there open it in AME, where the preview will work perfectly fine.

[image]